# Virtuoso SPARQL retrieving deleted RDF files

Tags: rdf, sparql, virtuoso

I am having a problem with my Virtuoso RDF Store.

I have uploaded some RDF files with the weather information. The information is repeated among the RDF files, so I decided to delete them. Although, when I make a SPARQL query, the information from the deleted RDF files is still retrieved.

Any idea of why is this happening? This is an example of a query I am making:

```
SELECT * 
FROM <miOnt:move>
WHERE 
  {
    ?ws <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type> <http://www.contextdatacloud.org/ontology/WeatherSituation>.
    ?ws <http://www.contextdatacloud.org/ontology/hasWeatherTime> ?time.
    ?time <http://www.w3.org/2006/time#inXSDDateTime> "2015-06-16T09:00:00".
    ?ws <http://www.contextdatacloud.org/ontology/hasTemperature> ?temperature
  }
```

I have used the cUrl command in Linux

`curl -T example01.rdf http://localhost:8890/home/myFolder/example01.rdf -u user:pass`

To delete them, I just used the option Delete from the Virtuoso UI:

[image: Virtuoso UI]

Thanks in advance

Comment: how did you upload them? how did you delete them? is the graph you're querying empty?

Comment: I upload them either using the Virtuoso UI and using the curl command.

"curl -T example01.rdf http://localhost:8890/home/myfolder/example01.rdf -u user:password"

And to delete them, I just simply used the Virtuoso UI.

I don't know the status of the graph. Where can I find it?

Answer (score 1):

In your example, the assumption is that by removing the .rdf documents you've removed them from the internal quad store named graph into which the .rdf document content (triples) was loaded. That isn't necessarily the case. Thus, try the following SPARQL command:

```
CLEAR GRAPH <miOnt:move> .
```

OR

```
DROP SILENT GRAPH <miOnt:move> .
```

Comment: So, if I understand you correctly... Once the triples are loaded, it doesn't work if I simply delete the RDF files? I need to clear the graph for that?